# How to find a TD tag having Input tag under it

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Need helps Guys
I have multiple TD tags in my html but i need to find a TD tag which is having INPUT tag in it.Currently i am hard-coding it and using td[7] like this

```
WebElement trs = GlobalVar.wDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//font[text()='Adjust Collection']/following::td[7]"));
```

Thanks
Devkant

Comment: Can you please post your html?

Answer (score 1):

With Xpath, you can find your input in the td. And then, you can go back to the parent element :

```
.xpath("//*[mypath]/td/input/..")
```

it goes back to the parent -> the td you are looking for

Comment: No problem. Can you mark my answer as useful ? Appreciate it !

Answer (score 0):

```
    try
    {
        IList<IWebElement> tdCollection = wDriver.FindElements(By.TagName("td"));

        foreach(IWebElement td in tdCollection)
        {
           try
           {
              IWebElement inputElement = td.FindElement(By.TagName("input"));
              // do your code
           }
           catch{}
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Surely a simple XPath like this would suffice:

```
//td/input
```

Find all `td` elements and filter that list to `td` elements that have an `input` element as an immediate child.